# How to implement navbar list with shadow in html/css?

Tags: css, html, drop-shadow

I have a design of `navbar` in mind that I want to implement for my web page. Please see the drawing I created using Inkscape.

[image: my design of navbar]

I read the [tutorial on w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html) and there is an example of adding padding to a list in `navbar`.

```
ul.navbar li {
background: white;
margin: 0.5em 0;
padding: 0.3em;
border-right: 1em solid black }
```

I am thinking if that method could be extended to create the shadow in my design or there is a better way.

Comment: downvotes without suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the shadow with the CSS's [`box-shadow`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/).

e.g.

```
box-shadow: .6em .6em 0 black;
```

The first two values are the offset values, the third is the blur radius (we want a solid shadow so set it to 0). There is an optional fourth numeric value that controls the spread (i.e. makes the shadow bigger or smaller; we've left that out). The last value is, obviously, the color.

A very quick full recreation of your menu would look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Pages</li>
</ul>
```

```
li {
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: .6em .6em 0 black;
}
```

Which should look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0bjzzvkd/):

[image]